# Hot swapping under RAID 1

Tags: raid1, mirroring, hotswap

I have a server that supports hot swapping (such as HP ProLiant DL160 G6 with hot swap) ([spec](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/uk/en/sm/WF25a/15351-15351-3328412-3328421-3328421-3884343.html)) and I configure it for RAID 1 mirroring across 2 disks.

Say one of the raid'ed disks then fails. Can I simply pull out the duff disk and replace it without rebooting the machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep that is exactly what hot swapping is all about. You can pull the disk at any time without having to turn off the server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I did that exact thing just last week with my virtual server. The 2nd disk started failing and I pulled it and even put a different manufacturer's disk (Fujitsu replaced a WD) in as the replacement. Let the RAID BIOS rebuild the HD and you are good to go.